# Game Object invisible for a given time

Tags: c#, game-engine, 2d-games

Good day everyone, currently I am developing a simple 2D game using SWINGAME. I have set a collision between 2 objects. So when they collide, I want to temporarily make one of them invisible for a certain time. I am stuck about the time component, let's say I want the object to be invisible for 3 seconds after that it will change back to the default object. Below are the two images, if the collision is true then it will display image2, or else display image1. BTW I use a different image to indicate the invisibility. Here's my code.

Player class:

```
 public void Draw ()
        {
            if (invisible == true) {
                if(elapsedTime <= 3.0){

                elapsedTime += elapsedTime;
                SwinGame.DrawBitmap ("image2.png", (float)X, (float)Y);

                  } 
            }else {
                elapsedTime = 0;
                SwinGame.DrawBitmap ("image1.png", (float)X, (float)Y);
            }
        }

  public bool Invisible {
        get { return invisible; }
        set { invisible = value; }
       }
```

Object Collision class :

```
{... //Some codes

    for(int i = 0; i < _obstacles.Count; i++)
    {
      if (_obstacles [i] is Invisible) {
         p.Invisible = true;
         p.Draw ();
           }
    }
//Some codes ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you to calculate the time accurately by using the [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
//somewhere in your code
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

public void Draw ()
        {
            if (invisible == true) {
                if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 3000){

                SwinGame.DrawBitmap ("image2.png", (float)X, (float)Y);

                  } 
            }else {
                sw.Restart();
                SwinGame.DrawBitmap ("image1.png", (float)X, (float)Y);
            }
        }
```

Comment: this makes the image visible for 3 seconds and will disappear after that. Any ideas?

Comment: I just added a timer and just copy-pasted your code. I need to see more code to try to help. Anyway I would suggest to check if you are setting the Visibility property to false somewhere in your code

Comment: 'p.invisible = true' might this be the issue? I don't get this part because you are drawing an invisible element. Either set visibility to true when you draw it or later on change visibility manually and set it to true

Comment: "p.Invisible = true" is to call the properties of getter and setter. My primary intention is to change a default image(image1) when it collides with another object to a different image(image2). And to make sure that the changed image last for few seconds. I am using an image to indicate the invisibility. I hope that this doesn't confuse you :)

Comment: I can tell you that on the else clause I suggested 'sw.Restart()' which start the timer again, you might consider 'sw.Reset()' if you want to start the timer later on manually. If that's not the issue then you better start debugging the code so you know which exact line makes the image disappear. Hope I helped :)